# Jboss 5 listen on different ip addresses based on different URL path

Tags: jboss5.x

We want to harden our Jboss server. We have a web application, and there are two types of resources in this web app
'https://myserver:8443/myapp/local/'
'https://myserver:8443/myapp/intranet/'

We only want the /myapp/local to be able to accessed from localhost 127.0.0.1 and the /myapp/intranet/ can be access from another address from internal network e.g. 192.168.12.12. Is there any way we can configure this? Thanks!

Tony

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Hope this is helpful for someone who runs into this someday. Here is the solution
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LimitAccessToCertainClients